# How to self join a CTE?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Hi This is the query i have created to fetch records from a history table This query is working fine but taking too much time to execute because it is selecting data twice from the table and the table has 20 millon or above records. So i want to optimize it. I will try to explain what this query does and what i want to achieve. 
I want to select two rows for each Id (ActivityId) from the table first is where the data is min and second where the date is maximum, So i can see how much progress happened in the mean time. Now what i am doing is first selecting the data where date is min as CTE and then selecting the data where date is maximum as CTE2. I can select both rows in a single CTE but I am not able to get a single record from both rows. Like i only need the Progress and Planned Field from the maximum date row and select all the other fields (most fields are common on both rows). So how can i achieve this. and please ask for clarification if needed.

CTE:

```
WITH cte AS 
( 
          SELECT    Row_number() OVER (partition BY pmaph.activityid ORDER BY date)    r1, 
                    pma.planenddate                                                 AS planenddate ,
                    pma.planstartdate                                               AS planstartdate,
                    pmaph.activityid, 
                    pmaph.projectmilestoneactivproghist_id                                                 AS promileavtiid,
                    umd.uom_name                                                                           AS uomname,
                    pmm.milestonename                                                                      AS milestonename,
                    pma.activityname                                                                       AS activityname ,
                    pmp.projectname                                                                        AS projectname,
                    Replace((Rtrim(Ltrim(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),Cast(pmaph.date AS DATETIME),106)))),' ','-') AS rdate, 
                    Isnull(pmaph.actual_progress,0)                                                        AS actualprogress,
                    Isnull(pmaph.planned_progress,0)                                                       AS plannedprogress
          FROM      projectmilestoneactivityprogresshistory                                                AS pmaph
          LEFT JOIN dbo.pm_project                                                                         AS pmp
          ON        pmaph.projectid=pmp.projectid 
          LEFT JOIN dbo.pm_activity AS pma 
          ON        pmaph.activityid=pma.activityid 
          LEFT JOIN dbo.pm_milestone AS pmm 
          ON        pmaph.milestoneid=pmm.milestoneid 
          LEFT JOIN dbo.uomdetail AS umd 
          ON        pma.uom_id=umd.uom_id 
          WHERE     pmaph.client_id=1030), cte2 AS( r2,isnull(pmaph.actual_progress,0) AS actualprogress, isnull(pmaph.planned_progress,0) AS plannedprogress, replace((rtrim(ltrim(CONVERT(varchar(12), cast(pmaph.date AS datetime),106)))),' ','-') AS rdate,pmaph.activityid FROM projectmilestoneactivityprogresshistory AS pmaph WHERE pmaph.client_id=1030)
SELECT cte2.rdate           AS todate, 
       cte2.actualprogress  AS end_actualprogress, 
       cte2.plannedprogress AS end_plannedprogress, 
       cte.actualprogress   AS start_actualprogress, 
       cte.plannedprogress  AS start_plannedprogress, 
       cte.rdate            AS fromdate , 
       cte.planenddate, 
       cte.planstartdate, 
       cte.activityid, 
       cte.uomname, 
       cte.milestonename, 
       cte.activityname, 
       cte.projectname 
FROM   cte 
JOIN   cte2 
ON     cte.activityid= cte2.activityid 
WHERE  cte.r1=1 
AND    cte2.r2=1
```

Comment: Just try to run without `Replace((Rtrim(Ltrim(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),Cast(pmaph.date AS DATETIME),106)))),' ','-') AS rdate` this column

Comment: I can't run without this because this column give me the date  to check what is the starting date and what is the end date. and other thing what will happen if i run without this. I just want to replace the cte2 and select all the data in CTE and select one record from two rows based on the common ActivityId,btw thanks for editing this question.